# Integrated Web-cam not detected

Tags: windows-10, lenovo-laptop, integrated-camera

I am using a Lenovo V330, and everytime I try using my integrated web-cam, it is not detected by the laptop. I tried locating it in the device manager but couldn't find it. I also tried reinstalling the driver but that didn't work too. How do I get it fixed?

Answer (score 0):

It may be disabled in BIOS. Look for some kind of peripherals options or USB settings (webcams are internally connected with a custom USB cable).

It's also possible that the webcam is physically disconnected. Fixing this problem would require disassembling the laptop.